# What is a good approach for modularizing MEAN applications?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I am getting started with developing MEAN applications and I am trying to use proper approaches regarding my workflow and code organization. I am currently using Gulp for automation and Bower for client side package management.
My current directory structure looks like the following:

```
.
  /app
    # welcome to the server
    /models
      # Mongoose models are here
    /routes
      # API routing is here
  /config
      # server side config files here (init.js and passport.js)
  /node_modules
      # this one is obvious
  /public
    # Angular is rocking over here
    /app
      app.js
      app.routes.js # this one is getting quite bloated
      /controllers
        # angular controllers
      /services
        # angular services
      /views
        index.html
        /pages
          # here I have directories for the views belonging to certain models
    /assets
      /css
      /img
      /js
      /libs
    /dist
      # gulp outputs compiled and/or minified CSS & JS here
```

My question is the following: I have tried MeanJS and MEAN.io, and while I feel like there is too much overhead in these setups, what I liked is that the whole application is modularized, each module residing in their own directory inside `/packages`, having their own client-side and server-side code inside that directory.

I know that this can easily become a question more of opinion than facts, but I would really like to know what are the best approaches toward modularizing an application, thus encapsulating certain features, making them possibly reusable and pluggable.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Also, let me add that I would also like to know what is the proper way to integrate testing into these modules.

Comment: I have written a blog post regarding the application structure in MEAN . May be that could help you . http://www.logicmanialab.com/2015/01/mean-js-application-structure.html